# How exactly can I get friends profile info like birthday,gender etc using google plus API?

Tags: android, google-plus

Can somebody please explain to me that what friends information I can get from google plus in android api in both worst and best case scenario.Some how I am not able to figure it out from google documentation.

I am using following code with scope and permission :-

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
```

to retrieve people info I am calling

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
                .setResultCallback(this);
```

Now is there any google api which I can use to get profile info of users and to what extent ?

Comment: onConnected is called upon succesful login ? if so you can get using Plus.PeopleApi. like..Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

Answer (score 0):

In onConnected method call the method getProfileInformation() , in this method you can get all the profile info

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();




 /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                **currentPerson.getBirthday();
                currentPerson.getGender();
                currentPerson.getRelationshipStatus();**
  } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for reply but I was looking for possibility of getting friend's information.Current authenticated person information I know can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can get any information with personBuffer.get(i) :

```
private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
public void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                if (loadPeopleResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                    PersonBuffer personBuffer = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer();
                    try {
                        int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            String name = personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName();
                            String nickName = personBuffer.get(i).getNickname();
                            String gender = personBuffer.get(i).getGender();
                            String urlPhoto = personBuffer.get(i).getImage().getUrl().substring(0,
                                            personBuffer.get(i).getImage().getUrl().length() - 2)
                                            + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                            //And other things...

                            if(personBuffer.get(i).getPlacesLived() != null || personBuffer.get(i).hasPlacesLived()) {

                                for (Person.PlacesLived place : personBuffer.get(i).getPlacesLived()) {
                                    if (place.isPrimary()) {
                                        String placesLived = place.getValue();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        personBuffer.close();
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```